# How to test AngularJS Jasmine service promise

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, promise, angular-services

I have the following service that I want to unit test.  I have mocked out the personService.deletePerson function and want to test the code inside the promise.

```
treeApp.factory('userMediatorService', ['$q', '$dialog', 'personService', 'confirmationMessageService',
    function ($q, $dialog, personService, confirmationMessageService) {

.......
deletePerson: function (personId) {
    var self = this;
    personService.deletePerson(personId).then(function (data) {
        //how to test this?
        self.closeAndRefresh();
        confirmationMessageService.set('Person Deleted');
    });
},
closeAndRefresh: function () {
    this.closeModal();
}
......
```

This is my test.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    sut = $injector.get('userMediatorService');
    personService = $injector.get('personService');
    q = $injector.get('$q');

    def = q.defer();

    spyOn(personService, 'deletePerson').andReturn(
        def.promise
    );
}));

describe('when a person is deleted', function () {
    it('should call the delete person service and close the modal', function () {
        sut.deletePerson(123);
        expect(personService.deletePerson).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123);  //pass
        expect(sut.closeAndRefresh).toHaveBeenCalled();  //fail
    });
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for testing this kind of scenario?  I realise that I can remove the spy on deletePerson, but then it wouldn't test this service in isolation.

Thanks.

**Update:**
I've tried using andCallFake as suggested by codemonkey and I still have the issue.

```
spyOn(personService, 'deletePerson').andCallFake(function () {
    def = q.defer();
    def.resolve(true);
    return def.promise;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the [`callFake`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies%3a_%3Ccode%3Eand.callFake%3C/code%3E) on the spy rather than `andReturn`. That will let you write a function that can resolve (or reject) the promise rather than just returning the promise.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this (see code in edit), but it didn't work for me.